# Find unknown matrix element using elementary row operation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus

> [image]
>
> Source: [ISI B-Math UGA 2017](https://www.isical.ac.in/%7Eadmission/IsiAdmission2017/PreviousQuestion/BStat-BMath-UGA-2017.pdf)

$A=\left(\begin{matrix}x &  5 & x \\  1 & 3 & -2\\ -2 &-2 &2 \end{matrix}\right)$

$B=\left(\begin{matrix}0 &  0 & 21 \\ 1  & -1 & -14\\ 0 &\frac{4}{3} &4\end{matrix}\right)$

Given if B can be obtained From A by applying finitely many basic row operation then what is value of x ?

One thing I did not understand the value of x be unique

Answer (score 3):

If this is true then we have $\det{(A)}=\det{(B)}$ hence
$$6x-2x+20+6x-4x-10=28$$
$$6x=18$$
$$x=3$$

Comment: Does it hold for elementary row operation or for this case only ?

Comment: See here - https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Effect_of_Elementary_Row_Operations_on_Determinant

Answer (score 1):

The point here must be that the "basic row operations" defined in the exercise are **not** the same as the usual *elementary row operations*. Namely, multiplying a row by a constant is not allowed.

This means that "basic row operations" *cannot change the determinant of the matrix*.

Can you find an $x$ such that the two matrices have the same determinant?

Comment: This reasoning really helps.. thanks!!